# Security and privacy of WhatsApp via Wi-Fi and in airplane mode

Tags: wireless-networking, security, isp, whatsapp

If my mobile phone is in airplane mode, and **afterwards** I activate the Wi-Fi in order to connect myself to a Wi-Fi network; is there any way for the ISP to know that my WhatsApp account (hence my phone number) was connected through them?

Comment: As I understand it, WhatsApp uses your phone number as an identifier, but doesn't actually use it like an SMS would.  I imagine all WhatsApp messages are sent using something like HTTPS to find the correct endpoint to deliver the message to.  If your ISP is reading your HTTPS requests, then you have bigger issues

Comment: @EricRoch the question should be more simcard oriented. Can the ISP recognize the simcard that's connecting to a wifi network (even if the mobile phone is on airplane mode)?

Comment: If my understanding of WhatsApp is correct, then they simply use your phone number as an "IP address" that tells their push notification server which app client to send the notification to.  Since the SIM is not used for WiFi, I don't think it would be involved in the interaction.  I am by no means an expert in either subject though, so take this with a grain of salt

Comment: I'm confused exactly what you're asking. The SIM information is not exposed to Wi-Fi. Unless you're dealing with state-level malicious actors, the wifi network has no way of seeing what the specific phone number is.

Comment: I just read through the [WhatsApp Security Whitepaper](https://www.whatsapp.com/security/WhatsApp-Security-Whitepaper.pdf) and, while most of it was talking about message encryption, it did mention that all metadata sent to and from the server is encrypted, and the service `Encrypts metadata to hide it from unauthorized network observers. No information about the connecting user’s identity is revealed`.  From this paper, I feel more confident in saying your phone number is purely an internal identifier and is not used for communication.

Comment: @plttn, He is asking whether an ISP could see the number associated with his WhatsApp account when connecting through WiFi.  Since that number is basically a username, and the metadata is encrypted, and since the SIM is not used in WiFi transmissions, my answer is no, they cannot.

Comment: @EricRoch i think your last comment clears the doubt.

Comment: @Roberto Great! I added an answer so others can find this more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WhatsApp Encryption Overview](https://www.whatsapp.com/security/WhatsApp-Security-Whitepaper.pdf) provides a description of how the app handles your data and how it is encrypted when communicating with the server and other users.  Near the end, the paper mentions how metadata is handled:

> All communication between WhatsApp clients and WhatsApp servers is layered within a separate encrypted channel. [This method] encrypts metadata to hide it from unauthorized network observers. No information about the connecting user’s identity is revealed.

From the [WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/20971813/?category=5245250),

> We ask for phone numbers because that's how WhatsApp identifies WhatsApp users, making it easier for you to message friends and family quickly.

So it seems that WhatsApp uses your phone number in leu of a username, but that identifier is still encrypted no matter which communication channel you are using (4G/LTE/WiFi).

Comment: Fixed your links markdown for you ...